# translate formula from glmer to glmmPQL

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, glmm

I want to translate this formula from `glmer()` (**lme4** package) to `glmmPQL()` (**MASS** package).

```
glmer(y ~ a + b + c + (a + b + c | x), 
      family = binomial())
```

I want to include the random intercept and the random slopes of all 3 predictors (`a`, `b`, `c`) in my model.

I have tried this one (not sure whether I rewrote the formula correctly), but it seems not working.

```
glmmPQL(y ~ a + b + c, random = ~ a + b + c | x, 
        family = binomial())
```

Here is the error message. Not exactly sure whether it was a formula error or convergence error.

```
Error in lme.formula(fixed = y ~ 1 + a + b + c, random = ~1 +  : 
  nlminb problem, convergence error code = 1
  message = iteration limit reached without convergence (10)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The translation from `glmer()` to `glmmPQL()` is correct. The error you receive indicates that the optimization algorithm behind `lme()` that is internally used in `glmmPQL()` did not converge successfully. You could try setting as optimization algorithm the `optim()` function instead of the `nlminb()` (the default).

But note that the `glmmPQL()` algorithm (penalized quasi likelihood) is inferior to the one behind `glmer()` (Laplace approximation). It is even better to use the adaptive Gaussian quadrature that is provided from the `mixed_model()` function of the [**GLMMadaptive**](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/) package. The equivalent code would be:

```
mixed_model(y ~ a + b + c, random = ~ a + b + c | x,
            family = binomial())
```

Comment: Thanks! It works now using the formula: glmmPQL(y ~ a + b + c, random = ~ a + b + c | x, family = binomial(), control=lmeControl(opt = "optim"))